# Difference between "return" and "return new"

Tags: c#, asp.net

While I reading extension methods in C#, I have come to see this below coding:

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static string UpperCaseFirstLetter(this string value)
    {
        if (value.Length > 0)
        {
            char[] array = value.ToCharArray();
            array[0] = char.ToUpper(array[0]);
            return new string(array);
        }
        return value;
    }
}
class Program : B
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    { 
        string value = "dot net";
        value = value.UpperCaseFirstLetter();
        Console.WriteLine(value);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

I commented the line, "return new" presents and run the program. Now the compiler reads the code "return value". If I run the program without commenting that line, then the compiler not reads the "return value" line.
What is the difference between return and return new in C#?

Comment: Those are just two `return` statements. When you take the first away, the program will always exit with the second one. The `new` is an ordinary object instantiation.

Comment: this doesn't really have anything to do with `return`.  They're just different objects

Comment: then what far they specified the new keyword there?

Comment: @thevan: Because they're creating a `new string()` on that line, to be returned.

Comment: Because they wanted to return a `string` while they had a `char` array. Luckily, there is a constructor for a `string` object that takes a `char` array as parameter.

Comment: So, even if we didn't use new keyword there, it also gives the same result. Correct?

Comment: Please don't use abbreviations such as "diff" and "b/w", instead of "different" and "between" in the title. Make it descriptive and easy to read.

Comment: No, you needed to construct a `string` because the method returns a `string`. You wouldn't be able to return a `char` array

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no such thing as `return new`. What is actually happening is:

```
string foo = new string(array);
return foo;
```

You are returning a instance of a string.

Answer (score 2):

There is no `return new`, it's just a `return` statement like any other.  What it's returning is `new string(array)`.

If you comment that line then the method doesn't end and instead exits the `if` block, proceeding to the next `return` statement.

Answer (score 1):

The return keyword will skip the execution and return the value which function has as a return type. In your example it's  `static string` so it's returning you the string.

FROM OP:

```
I commented the line, "return new" presents and run the program. Now the compiler reads the code "return value". If I run the program without commenting that line, then the compiler not reads the "return value" line. What is the difference between return and return new in C#?
```

When you commented the line "return new" the compiler execute the whole function block and "return value" get's executed and when the "return new" present there then the compiler reads it and return flow from there.

Answer (score 1):

I think the `return` has confused you.  Take this logically equal code:

```
public static string UpperCaseFirstLetter(this string value)
{
    string result;

    if (value.Length > 0)
    {
        char[] array = value.ToCharArray();
        array[0] = char.ToUpper(array[0]);
        result = new string(array);
    }
    else
    {
        result = value;
    }

    return result;
}
```

`new string(array)` is calling [this constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttyxaek9%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that takes a char array and gives you a string representation of it.  The method signature states that a `string` will be returned.  If you attempted `return array`, a compiler error would occur.

Comment: Yes.. So here we are using new keyword to convert the char array to string.. Correct?

Comment: you are using the `new` keyword to instantiate a new string, then calling one of the string constructor overloads that accepts a char array.